# document.querySelector retornando null

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando preencher uma tabela HTML com dados de um BD SqlServer.

### Minha tabela HTML:

```
var overViewForm = '<h3>OVERVIEW</h3>' +
                       '<table id="modelTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">' +
                           '<thead>' +
                               '<tr>' +
                                  '<th>idInstallation</th>' +
                                  '<th>project_Code</th>' +
                                  '<th>runId</th>' +
                                  '<th>block</th>' +
                                  '<th>input</th>' +
                                  '<th>state</th>' +
                                  '<th>operation</th>' +
                                  '<th>allDescription</th>' +
                                  '<th>reducedDescription</th>' +
                                  '<th>tstId</th>' +
                               '</tr>' +
                           '</thead>' +
                           '<tbody></tbody>' +
                       '</table>';
    
function overViewPrefab() {
    return overViewForm;
}
```

obs: Esta tabela esta dentro de um arquivo JavaScript. Quando eu crio ela no HTML o código não apresenta problemas.

### JavaScript que preenche a tabela:

```
tableBody = document.querySelector("#modelTable > tbody");
    
function loadData() {

    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    request.open("get", "http://localhost:52691//api/AppLock/run/all");
    
    request.onload = () => {
        const json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        populateTable(json);

    };

    request.send();

}

function populateTable(json) {
    // Populate table
    json.forEach((row) => {
        const tr = document.createElement("tr");

        Object.keys(row).forEach((cell) => {
            const td = document.createElement("td");
            td.textContent = cell;
            tr.appendChild(td);
        });

        tableBody.appendChild(tr);
    });
}
```

Importante falar que estou chamando estes scripts na parte de baixo do HTML, também estou conseguindo recuperar os dados do BD, o problema esta na hora de preencher a tabela.
Já debuguei  o código inteiro, aparentemente o problema esta na primeira linha do JavaScript:

> tableBody = document.querySelector("#modelTable > tbody");

que sempre retorna null.

Não estou conseguindo identificar o porque deste erro estar acontecendo nem como resolvê-lo. Gostaria que alguém pudesse me explicar o porque disto estar acontecendo, e me dar uma dica de como solucionar este problema.

Comment: Testando aqui não apresentou nenhum erro e a tabela foi populada normalmente. Deve ter algo a mais que vc não mencionou e que deve ser a causa do erro.

Comment: @Sam Algumas informações que possam ajudar. A tabela esta dentro de um arquivo JavaScript. Quando eu coloco a tabela no HTML ela preenche normalmente.

Comment: Como assim "dentro de um arquivo JavaScript"? Não entendi.

Comment: @Sam estou utilizando estes arquivos JavaScript como templates, desta forma estou mudando as informações da minha div conforme eu chamo estes templates, utilizando innerHTML.

Comment: Sugiro que edite a pergunta e coloque o código como está. Vc está falando informações que não estão na pergunta e que influenciam bastante no resultado.

Comment: @Sam pergunta editada

Comment: Vc tem que chamar `tableBody = document.querySelector("#modelTable > tbody");` depois que insere a tabela no HTML

Comment: @Sam ai que esta o problema, no index.html estou chamando o script da tabela antes do script que carrega a tabela. Isto já não deveria ser o suficiente ?

Comment: Depende. Ao fazer `tableBody = document.querySelector("#modelTable > tbody");`, a tabela deve estar no HTML, senão retorna null mesmo.

Comment: @Sam alguma dica de como fazer isto ?

Comment: consegui resolver o problema. Eu estava declarando tableBody = document.querySelector("#modelTable > tbody"); fora de uma função, tudo que fiz foi mover para dentro da função que preenchia a table.

Comment: Provavelmente a table ainda não está pronta, então ele não consegue, identificar o ID, você pode tentar usar: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   //verifica se o documento está pronto
  });`